# How do I find an index of an element in an array matching a condition and starting the search from a particular point in the array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, indexof

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  I know how to find all the indexes in an array of elements matching a condition ...

```
arr.each_index.select{|i| arr[i] == 'x'}
```

but how do I find the index of the first element that matches a condition starting from a particular position in teh array?  So what if I wanted to find a string with only a single character at or after index = 2? (If tehre are less than 2 elements the operation can return nil).  So for example, if I have

```
["abc", "d", "efg", "h", "abcde"]
```

the operation would return "3", since element "h" is at position 3, only has a single character and is at or after index 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect) would return all values where the block returns `true` for example:

```
p arr = ["abc", "d", "efg", "h", "abcde", "k"]
# => ["abc", "d", "efg", "h", "abcde", "k"]
p arr.each_index.select{|i| i >= 2 and arr[i].length == 1}
# => [3, 5]
```

Instead use [`detect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect) if you want to return only the first value where the block returns `true`:

```
p arr = ["abc", "d", "efg", "h", "abcde", "k"]
# => ["abc", "d", "efg", "h", "abcde", "k"]
p arr.each_index.detect{|i| i >= 2 and arr[i].length == 1}
# => 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array#index` with `with_index`:

```
arr = ["abc", "d", "efg", "h", "abcde"]
arr.index.with_index { |el, idx| el.length == 1 && idx > 2 }
 => 3 

arr = ["abc", "d"]
arr.index.with_index { |el, idx| el.length == 1 && idx > 2 }
 => nil
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def first_index_after(arr, min_ndx)
  min_ndx.upto(arr.size-1).find { |i| yield(arr[i]) }
end

arr = ["abcdef", "h", "efgh", "h", "abcde", "h"]
min_ndx = 2

first_index_after(arr, min_ndx) { |e| e == "h" }     #=> 3 
first_index_after(arr, min_ndx) { |e| e =~ /\Ah\z/ } #=> 3 
first_index_after(arr, min_ndx) { |e| e =~ /h/ }     #=> 2 
first_index_after(arr, min_ndx) { |e| e.size > 4 }   #=> 4 
first_index_after(arr, min_ndx) { |e| e == 'cat' }   #=> nil
```

This assumes `0 <= min_ndx < arr.size`. It may be desirable to add a first line to the method that returns `nil` or raises an exception if this requirement is not satisfied.